# Why are these variables getting cleared/reset?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a small library for scrolling events in JavaScript, but I must be missing something easy, because it seems that my vars are getting reset at some point inside of this method.

Here is the code:

```
var scrollEvents = {
  change: window.onscroll = function (selector, property, initialValue, changedValue) {
    // grab the selectors and convert them into an array so we can use forEach()
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    var itemArray = [].slice.call(items);
    // window.pageYOffset has better compatibility than document.body.scrollTop
    var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var breakPoint = 10;
    if (scrollPos > breakPoint) {
      console.log('if');
      console.log(items);
      console.log(itemArray);
      itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
        i.setAttribute("style", property + ": " + changedValue + ";");
        console.log("style", property + ": " + changedValue + ";")
      });
    } else {
      console.log('else');
      console.log(itemArray);
      itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
        i.setAttribute("style", property + ": " + initialValue + ";");
      });
    }
  }
};
```

And I would like to call it like so:

```
scrollEvents.change("foo", "height", "400px", "800px");
```

I have quite a few extra `console.log()` calls inside there because I have been trying to diagnose the issue, but I have rewritten the code several times and seem to have hit a dead end.

The behavior I would like is that I can call `scrollEvents.change()` passing those parameters to change style attributes at certain scroll points.

Here is the code without all the extra `console.log()`'s:

```
var scrollEvents = {
  change: window.onscroll = function (selector, property, initialValue, changedValue) {
    // grab the selectors and convert them into an array so we can use forEach()
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    var itemArray = [].slice.call(items);
    // window.pageYOffset has better compatibility than document.body.scrollTop
    var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var breakPoint = 10;
    if (scrollPos > breakPoint) {
      itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
        i.setAttribute("style", property + ": " + changedValue + ";");
      });
    } else {
      itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
        i.setAttribute("style", property + ": " + initialValue + ";");
      });
    }
  }
};
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to @pointy this library now works: https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/scrollEvents

Comment: @Adi ??? What?  That's not anywhere close to the problem, and it's not true anyway.

Comment: My bad, but what I was trying to say is similar to YUI modules concept. e.g. http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set up an object with a property called "change", and you've assigned a function to that property. The assignment *also* assigned the function to the "onscroll" property of the `window` object.

When the browser detects a user scroll operation, it will invoke that function, and regardless of your formal parameter list in the declaration it'll pass either nothing (Internet Explorer) or an event object.

Making a call to `scrollEvents.change` will invoke the event handler function, but that will have no effect on how the browser invokes the event handler when the user messes with the scrollbar or mouse wheel (or whatever).

I'm not sure exactly how you intend for this API to work, so it's hard to say how to fix it. If you want to attach just one event handler at a time, then the simplest thing to do would be to wrap your current code in another function:

```
var scrollEvents = {
  change: function (selector, property, initialValue, changedValue) {
    window.onscroll = function(event) {
      // grab the selectors and convert them into an array so we can use forEach()
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
      var itemArray = [].slice.call(items);
      // window.pageYOffset has better compatibility than document.body.scrollTop
      var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      var breakPoint = 10;
      if (scrollPos > breakPoint) {
        itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
          i.setAttribute("style", property + ": " + changedValue + ";");
        });
      } else {
        itemArray.forEach(function (i) {
          i.setAttribute("style", property + ": " + initialValue + ";");
        });
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Now when you call

```
scrollEvents.change("foo", "height", "400px", "800px");
```

then that function call will establish the event handler.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you! This is precisely how I wanted it to work.

Comment: Here is the repo if you are curious: https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/scrollEvents